# How to align right in BootStrap 5.0 for the components?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am actually trying to do this online course and in that the instructor uses Bootstrap 4, but I decided I could do BootStrap 5.1.

I am trying to make my navigator bar elements like the ordered list on the right, but I checked the documentation and everything, I can't seem to figure why it's not working.

So my current navigation bar is something like:
[image]

So I can't seem to get it there, I used these different variations:

1. ```
     <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end">
   ```
2. ```
     <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
   ```
3. ```
     <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto>
   ```

Also, Could someone help me understand what does me? mb? ml stand for?
And how do I get this to right side in BootStrap 5.0

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Priyanka Giri</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Name ABC</a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ml-2">
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Education</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Experience</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE: ms-auto WORKED But what does this mean exactly? What did the above three mean?**

Comment: try ms-auto https://prnt.sc/1sov38i

Comment: It worked @AlaksandarJesusGene what does it mean?

Comment: In bootstrap 4 they used a term as left. In bootstrap 5 it is marked as start;    In boostrap 4 they used term right, in bootstrap 5 it is marked as end.

Comment: In flex box design they use start and end. So bootstrap used start and end instead of left and right.

Comment: I don't understand what B4 Left etc is? Could you share some resources that I could read? I am a beginner to Bootstrap

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/

Comment: as said `ms` standas for "margin start". They uses now `start` and `end` to make it "easier" for all. The thing is that `start` is not always the left. In `RTL` it would be the right side. `margin: auto` in flexbox will make the margin consume all remaing space. Thats how it works in this case.

Answer (score 1):

- `.me` is the renamed classname of `.mr`, which stands for
  `margin-right` property
- `.mb` is the classname which stands for `margin-bottom` property
- `.ml` is the classname which stands for `margin-left` property

Since Bootstrap 5 `.ml` has been renamed to `.ms`, and `.mr` has been renamed to `.me`.

More on that in the documentation of migrating to v5: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/

Speaking of your code, the `.ml-auto` class sets your nav-items on the left. It simply sets the `margin-left: auto;` CSS. This may not work in the newer Bootstrap. Try renamed the version with `.ms-auto`, so your code will look like:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Priyanka Giri</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Name ABC</a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto ms-2">
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Education</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Experience</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just one question, Why do we then still do ms-auto ml-2

So is the ml-2 like margin left 2?

Comment: You're right. We should use ms-2 there. I have just edited the code block.

Comment: Really sorry but one more question , I tried doing ms-10 and then even ms-10px I can't see a visible change? Why so?

Comment: Sizes range from 0 to 5 by the default. E.g: ms-0, ms-1, ms-2, ms-3, ms-4, ms-5

Comment: Okayy, Thank you!